# PHP get magic method not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, magic-methods

This is what I have currently:

```php
class Cart
{
    protected $user;
    public function __construct(User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user ?? auth()->user();
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if($name == 'coupon') {
            if (session()->has('coupon') && session()->get('coupon')->canBeUsed($this->total()) ) {
                $coupon = session()->get('coupon');
                $coupon->refresh();
                return $coupon;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
    public function couponDiscount(){
        if($this->coupon) {
            return $this->coupon->realDiscount($this->subtotal());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However if i try to invoke `couponDiscount` i get `Undefined property`.. why?

EDIT: seems something on the server, on local `app()->make(\App\Supports\Cart::class)->couponDiscount()` will return 0 and not `undefined property` (I'm using Laravel 6.x)

Comment: if this fails, then you won't have a valid coupon and  realDiscount will be undefined.            if (session()->has('coupon') && session()->get('coupon')->canBeUsed($this->total()) ) I am guessing you don't have a coupon in your seesion

Comment: @bumperbox yes but laravel is reporting that error in the "if" line of code, so has nothing to do with the logic i believe